# Declaring variables in CTEs SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I implement something like the following:

```
declare @myInt int
set @myInt=(select count(*) from x)
;with x as

(
select row_number() over(partition by c.patientid order by c.admissiondate) as rn
    ,c.patientid,c.admissiondate
    ,max(c.claimsfromdate)  as maxHemiDate
    ,min(c.claimsfromdate) minHemiDate  
    ,(
        select max(c2.claimsfromdate)
            from claims as c2
            where c2.patientid=c.patientid
            group by c2.patientid
     ) as maxClaimsDate

         ,p.drgCode
         ,datediff(dd,min(c.claimsfromdate),max(c.claimsfromdate)) /7 as weeksWithHemi
         from claims as c inner join icdclaims as ci on ci.id=c.id
         inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id=ci.icd_id
         inner join patient as p on p.patientid=c.patientid
         and p.admissiondate = c.admissiondate
         and p.dischargedate = c.dischargedate
         where t.icdText like '%X%'  and p.statecode='21'
         group by c.patientid, c.admissiondate, p.drgCode
)

select p.patientid, count(*)
    from patient as p
    left join x on x.patientid=p.patientid
    where x.patientid is null
    group by p.patientid
```

The error thrown when this is executed is

> *invalid object name x*

I kinda figured that this would happen since the variable declaration is outside of the CTE. If I move the declaration inside of the parentheses of `WITH` I get another error.

How can I assign a variable like this inside a CTE? Or can you not use a variable that draws data from the CTE at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can put the total on each row:

```
select t.*, cnt, count(*) over () as NumRows
from (select p.patientid, count(*) as cnt
      from patient as p left join
           x
           on x.patientid=p.patientid
      where x.patientid is null
      group by p.patientid
    ) t
```

In case you are using the total to calculate percentages, or something like that, it might be convenient to have the value on each row.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović . . . I like to put *something* between the parentheses, to make the intent more apparent.

Comment: Yes, but this produces `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'.`. You might have put `partition by null`, but null by itself will not work.

Answer (score 3):

To get in @myInt number of rows, you can do:

```
declare @myInt int
;with x as
(
   __your query__
)
select p.patientid, count(*)
    from patient as p
    left join x on x.patientid=p.patientid
    where x.patientid is null
    group by p.patientid


set @myInt=@@ROWCOUNT
```

***EDITED*** (Due  Jon Egerton comment) If you need to count x rows, then a temporay table is the way:

```
declare @myInt int
;with x as
(
   __your query__
)
select * 
into #tmp_x
from x;

set @myInt=(select count(*) from #tmp_x)

select p.patientid, count(*)
    from patient as p
    left join #tmp_x x on x.patientid=p.patientid
    where x.patientid is null
    group by p.patientid
```

Thanks  Jon Egerton

Comment: That will show the number of rows in the returned data, not the number of rows in the `x` CTE though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

`set @myInt=(select count(*) from x)`

You are trying to do the select on `x` before it has been declared!

**UPDATE**

In this case it would be best to use a temporary table or table variable rather than a CTE. For example:

```
declare @myInt int

select row_number() over(partition by c.patientid order by c.admissiondate) as rn
    ,c.patientid,c.admissiondate
    ,max(c.claimsfromdate)  as maxHemiDate
    ,min(c.claimsfromdate) minHemiDate  
    ,(
        select max(c2.claimsfromdate)
            from claims as c2
            where c2.patientid=c.patientid
            group by c2.patientid
     ) as maxClaimsDate

         ,p.drgCode
         ,datediff(dd,min(c.claimsfromdate),max(c.claimsfromdate)) /7 as weeksWithHemi
         INTO #XTable
         from claims as c inner join icdclaims as ci on ci.id=c.id
         inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id=ci.icd_id
         inner join patient as p on p.patientid=c.patientid
         and p.admissiondate = c.admissiondate
         and p.dischargedate = c.dischargedate
         where t.icdText like '%X%'  and p.statecode='21'
         group by c.patientid, c.admissiondate, p.drgCode

set @myInt=(select count(*) from #XTable)

select p.patientid, count(*)
    from patient as p
    left join #XTable x on x.patientid=p.patientid
    where x.patientid is null
    group by p.patientid
```

This is the quick and dirty method, but you could obviously declare your table earlier in the script.

Comment: When he moves that though, the second select at the bottom will fail.

Comment: @alex right, i understand that.  like i said, i didn't think it would execute. i'm asking for how this could be circumvented.

Comment: Ah, I get you now. That's because a CTE will be consumed by the next SELECT statement. In this case I would use a temporary table.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a single `CTE` for two distinct statements - they go out of scope.

So either you need to remove the need for the variable, or you can just declare a table variable and then keep selecting on that as many times as you like.

You can declare table var as follows:

```
declare @x table (rowno int, patientid varchar...
```

Then you can fill that using the select that you've currently got in your CTE.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE may be plural.  It doesn't solve your stated problem, but it is often clearer to break a complex CTE into several steps, each building on the prior definitions.  In this example there is a recursive CTE and a second CTE that computes statistics based on the first.  The final `SELECT` combines the results:

```
with CTE
  as (
    select 1 as Number
    union all
    select Number + 1
      from CTE
      where Number < 10
    ),
  Summary
  as (
    select Count( 42 ) as HowMany, Min( Number ) as Least, Max( Number ) as Most
      from CTE
    )
  select *
    from CTE cross join
      Summary
```